# consider $4x^2 + y^2 = 4$. What I have if $x=0$?

Tags: conic-sections

I need to graph the following surface: $4x^2 + y^2 = 4$ which is an ellipse, so canonical equation is $x^2 + (y^2)/4 = 1$. Then, to graph this I can say:

If $x=0$:

$y^2 = 4$

so $y = 2$ or $y = -2$

But what I have in the plane? two parallels lines? because I just see two points at that coords in the following graph:

[image: click me]

Comment: Could you possibly expand a bit on your question? At $x=0$ you have correctly identified that $y=\frac+{}2$, what's the problem?

Comment: @Aka_aka_aka_ak, you can use `$\pm$` for $\pm$.

Comment: @tilper oh thanks

Comment: What is the question, exactly?

Comment: @Aka_aka_aka_ak Can I say there's two paralel lines  if I don't see that lines on the plane?

Comment: Well, that graph is only one crosssection of the entire surface that in 3D space is a tube.  If you expand those two points into the front and back third dimension they will expand into two parallel lines just like the ellipse will expand into a tube.

Comment: The lines aren't on the xy plane.  They are on the yz plane that goes from your eyeballs to the screen.  The two lines are poking two holes into your computer screen and piercing you skull and going out the back of your house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are graphing in xyz space the surface is a tube with a constant x/y cross section being an ellipse for any $z = k$.

If you take the y/z cross section at $x = 0$ this is cutting the tube lengthwise in half and seeing the cut lines.  The result is two parallel lines.

That's exactly what you should expect.

If you are graphing only on the x-y plane the this is an ellipse.  Setting $x = 0$ gives you the two points on the ellipse where $x =0$.  That there are two points and they are $(0,2)$ and $(0,-2)$ should not surprise any one.

Answer (score 0):

You get parallel lines when $y= -2$ or $ y = $ any constant $c$ FOR EVERY $x$. Please be careful, in the context or your question its only the case that $y= 2$ or $y = -2$ when $x=0$ not at any other points.

Comment: Nitpicky: if $x = \pm 1$ you only get one point and if $|x| > 1$ you get none.

Comment: Can I say there's two paralel lines if I don't see that lines on the plane?

Comment: The plane is only one cross section.  The surface is in ***THREE*** dimensions.  The lines are going ***THROUGH*** the plane and intersecting the plane at two *points*.

Comment: @fleablood OP didn't specify whether it was 2D or 3D

Comment: True.  But the OP referred to it as a "surface" and given the result y = 2 and y = -2  interpreted those as being equations for parallel lines. So it is implied.